# Add an include path for a single file in a library

Tags: c++, build, waf

I'm building a library for which *one file* requires an additional include path. Is there a way to adjust the include path for compilation of a single file?

```
     bld(features="cxx cxxshlib",
         source=[so, many, files, from an ant_glob],
         includes=[Some path that's really only needed for one interface file])
```

I'd be happy with a solution that is `use` based, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think most solutions will be more lines of code than just compiling your one file separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the specfic file by using `objects` and then `use` the result.

Something like this:

```py
def build(bld):
    # build the specfifc object
    bld.objects(source="foo.cpp", includess="path/to/directory", target="foo")
    # build the library and include that object file using 'use='
    bld.stlib(source='bla.cpp blu.cpp', includes="this/path that/path", target='mylibrary', use='foo')
```

Comment: When I do this, the per-object use is skipped at the link step

Comment: If you don't link with the library, you need to use the ``use`` keyword and the object file to used as argument in your linking step also.